# Split circle into horizontal lines

Tags: geometry, circles

Can you create a function that splits circle into $n$ lines that their sum gives the area of circle. For some x I want the function or formula to return the length of a horizontal line in the circle

Comment: I love the idea but i m not sure to understand what your talking about. Can you be a little bit more explicit/formal ?

Comment: Try to be clearer; also, what does this have to do with logic?

Comment: Can you define what is the volume of the circle?

Comment: @Vasya I mean the area

Comment: May the lines intersect?

Answer (score 0):

One way to parameterize 
the first quadrant of a circle is
$p(t)
=(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})$
for
$0 \le t \le 1$.
This works because
$(2t)^2+(1-t^2)^2
=4t^2+1-2t^2+t^4
=1+2t^2+t^4
=(1+t^2)^2
$.

I'm going to use this
to try to get 
the area of the circle.

Consider the lines from
$p(-t)$ to $p(t)$
for 
$t = 0, 1/n, 2/n, ... n/n$.
These will slice the
top half of the circle
into $n$ parts.

The length of the $k$-th one is
$2\frac{2k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}
=\frac{4kn}{n^2+k^2}
$.

The distance between the lines is

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1-((k-1)/n)^2}{1+((k-1)/n)^2}-\frac{1-(k/n)^2}{1+(k/n)^2}
&=\frac{n^2-(k-1)^2}{n^2+(k-1)^2}-\frac{n^2-k^2}{n^2+k^2}\\
&=\frac{(n^2+k^2)(n^2-(k-1)^2)-(n^2-k^2)(n^2+(k-1)^2)}{(n^2+(k-1)^2)(n^2+k^2)}\\
&=\frac{(4 k - 2) n^2}{(n^2+(k-1)^2)(n^2+k^2)}\\
\end{array}
$

The area
of the $k$-th slice
 is thus about

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{4kn}{n^2+k^2}\frac{(4 k - 2) n^2}{(n^2+(k-1)^2)(n^2+k^2)}
&=\frac{4k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}\frac{(4k /n - 2/n)}{(1+(k/n-1/n)^2)(1+(k/n)^2)}\frac1{n}\\
&\approx\frac{(4k/n)^2}{(1+(k/n)^2)^3}\frac1{n}\\
&=16\frac{(k/n)^2}{(1+(k/n)^2)^3}\frac1{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Using these as a Riemann sum,
the area of the top half of the circle
is,
letting $n \to \infty$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n16\frac{(k/n)^2}{(1+(k/n)^2)^3}\frac1{n}
&=16\int_0^1 \frac{x^2dx}{(1+x^2)^3}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

since,
according to Wolfy,

$\int \dfrac{x^2dx}{(1+x^2)^3}
= \frac18 \left(\frac{x (x^2 - 1)}{(x^2 + 1)^2} + \tan^{-1}(x)\right) 
$